# Group List of Map Data into Nested HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, grouping, collectors

Input: I have a list of Map (Key - Value pairs) and grouping keys

e.g.`List<Map<String,String>> inputData` json

```
[
 {
    'a': 'German',
    'b': 'Audi',
    'e': 'T3'
 },
 {
    'a': 'German',
    'b': 'BMW',
    'c': 'T6'
 },
 {
    'a': 'American',
    'b': 'Tesla',
    'c': 'T6'
 }
]
```

and groupingKeys= `a and b`

For Grouping key a -> I will create two buckets, one for German and other American and in each bucket I will again create bucket for value of b, check following

I want to produce following:  `Map<String, Map<String, List<Map>>` - the nesting of maps  == number of grouping keys, here it's 2

```
{
   German: {
       Audi: [
            {
               'a': 'German',
               'b': 'Audi',
               'e': 'T3'
            }
       ],
       BMW: [
            {
               'a': 'German',
               'b': 'BMW',
               'c': 'T6'
            }
       ]
   },
   American: {
      Tesla: [
          {
            'a': 'American',
            'b': 'Tesla',
            'c': 'T6'
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

Things I tried:

```
inputData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(mapItem -> this.constructGroupingKey(groupingKeys, mapItem)));

//constructGroupingKey - this joins the values of of given grouping keys
```

This way I can construct concatenated key e.g German-Audi OR German-BMW  and save the matching item against it but it's not what I want exactly.

As @Naman said here about concrete class - following makes it one liner but I can't make assumptions about data, it's of type Map

`Map<String, Map<String, List<ConcreteClass>>> output = inputData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ConcreteClass::getCountry, Collectors.groupingBy(ConcreteClass::getCarType)));`

Would appreciate other ideas, thanks. I am also curious if I can derive grouping based on given data without specification of grouping keys.

Input is of dynamic nature, key and value are defined by the input

Comment: Use concrete objects! Another way, try and share the type of your output and look at the complexity driven there.

Comment: Could you use nested Maps? Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> where the first Map's key is a country, second Map's is a company and the last one stores models?

Comment: yeah I can,  Can I derive it based on the nature of keys automatically, the nesting will increase based on number of grouping keys,  I can't  assume it's just two levels of nesting

Comment: @Naman,  the input is of type Map<String, String> , I can not make assumptions about data, creating concrete class would require me to specify field names?

Answer (score 1):

Just to double click on the representation of the input as concrete class. It would look much simpler and clean as :

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<ThrowAway>>> multipleGrouping(List<ThrowAway> inputData) {
    return inputData.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ThrowAway::getA,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(ThrowAway::getB)));
}
```

where I just created a sample class same as your map representation:

```
class ThrowAway {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;

    String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    String getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poor naming convention! Agreed, yet it's more about portraying the approach here.

Comment: Are you saying from given input of  Map<String,String> --> derive class ThrowAway ? 

The input will change, we can't map everything to ThrowAway ?

Comment: @Pradeep What I am trying to convey is that there are certain guarantees assumed as per the question itself. For e.g. is it possible to have the input in the form `[
 {
    'a': 'German',
    'b': 'Audi',
    'e': 'T3'
 },
 {
    'a': 'German',
    'b': 'BMW',
    'c': 'T6'
 },
 {
    'd': 'American',
    'e': 'Tesla',
    'f': 'T6'
 }
]` and then what do you expect the output to be? There has to be some kind of contracts to determine the keys to group with at least.

Comment: we can not assume input form but I can ask caller to preregister the grouping keys, the output is always nested based on the grouping keys

Comment: @Pradeep and preregistering the keys is defining a concrete object in my understanding. Also, seems like you're ignoring the kind of role inheritance can play in here.

Comment: so System A is running somewhere, System B is running somewhere, we get these grouping keys at runtime,  by registering means we store somewhere in storage that the keys a and b will be required from grouping, keys can change at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a dynamic solution, here is another approach:

You can use the following grouping method to pass two keys for:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> group(List<Map<String, String>> list, String key1, String key2) {
    return list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get(key1),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get(key2))
            )
    );
}
```

The problem here is if the key does not exist in the map you are getting a `NullPointerException`. To prevent this you can use `map.getOrDefault()` with a default key:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> group(List<Map<String, String>> list, String key1, String key2, String noneKey) {
    return list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getOrDefault(key1, noneKey),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getOrDefault(key2, noneKey))
            )
    );
}
```

Call one of the methods with the following options:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> result = group(list, "a", "b");
```

Or

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> result = group(list, "a", "b", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON library such as *Josson* to do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"a\": \"German\"," +
    "        \"b\": \"Audi\"," +
    "        \"e\": \"T3\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"a\": \"German\"," +
    "        \"b\": \"BMW\"," +
    "        \"c\": \"T6\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"a\": \"American\"," +
    "        \"b\": \"Tesla\"," +
    "        \"c\": \"T6\"" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "group(a).map(a::elements.group(b).map(b::elements).mergeObjects()).mergeObjects()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "German" : {
    "Audi" : [ {
      "a" : "German",
      "b" : "Audi",
      "e" : "T3"
    } ],
    "BMW" : [ {
      "a" : "German",
      "b" : "BMW",
      "c" : "T6"
    } ]
  },
  "American" : {
    "Tesla" : [ {
      "a" : "American",
      "b" : "Tesla",
      "c" : "T6"
    } ]
  }
}
```